# Wicket: Conditional display in Template

Tags: java, templates, wicket

Hy,
I want to display a certain part (a div for example) of my wicket-template only under a certain condition (for example only if I have the data to fill it). The problem is:

If I only add the panel (filling the div) if I got the data, an exception is thrown every time I call the page without the data (because the referenced wicket-id is not added to the component-tree).

*The only solution which came to my mind was to add a empty panel if there is no data. This is not an ideal solution because I got some unneeded code in the java-code and many empty divs in my rendered html.*

**So is there a better solution to include several parts of a wicket-template only under a condition?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although this is an old question here could be one more solution: [wicket:enclosure](http://www.systemmobile.com/?page_id=253) (and [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=wicket+conditional+markup) )

**Update**: Now I needed this functionality by my self (for [jetwick](https://github.com/karussell/Jetwick)). I'm using WebMarkupContainer one for loggedIn state and one for loggedOut state and set the right  visibility:

```
if (loggedIn()) {            
   WebMarkupContainer loggedInContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("loggedIn");
   //## do something with the user
   User user = getUserSomeWhere();
   loggedInContainer.add(new UserSearchLink("userSearchLink"));
   add(loggedInContainer);
   add(WebMarkupContainer("loggedOut").setVisible(false));
} else {
   add(new WebMarkupContainer("loggedIn").setVisible(false));
   WebMarkupContainer loggedOutContainer = WebMarkupContainer("loggedOut");
   loggedOutContainer.add(new LoginLink() {...});
   add(loggedOutContainer);
}
```

The advantage of this for me is that I prevent a NullpointerExc in the //## marked line and the enclose feature of wicket would look more ugly to me in this case I think.

Answer (score 3):

Like @miaubiz said, you can call setVisible(false), or you can override the isVisible() method, if the visibility is conditional to some other state (fields filled, for example).

Answer (score 3):

Yup, you want to override isVisible.  This will keep the isVisible=false html markup from even rendering to the final html page.  Also, according to the docs (mentioned in [EmptyPanel](http://wicket.apache.org/docs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/panel/EmptyPanel.html)), you can use the [WebMarkupContainer](http://wicket.apache.org/docs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/WebMarkupContainer.html) as the wrapping component.

```
    this.add(new SimpleResourceModelLabel(NO_DATA_LABEL){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public boolean isVisible() { return myList.isEmpty(); } 
    });

    final WebMarkupContainer table = new WebMarkupContainer(MY_DATA_TABLE){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public boolean isVisible() { return !myList.isEmpty(); } 
    };
```

Comment: More from the wicket docs (https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/lifecycle-of-a-wicket-application.html):

Component.render() follows these steps to render a component:
1. Determine component visibility. If the component is not visible,
the RequestCycle's Response is changed to NullResponse.getInstance(),
which is a Response implementation that simply discards its output.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is why there's [EmptyPanel](http://wicket.apache.org/docs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/panel/EmptyPanel.html). Without knowing about your code more I can only say that what I think you're doing is something I'd do with combination of some child of [AbstractRepeater](http://wicket.apache.org/docs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/repeater/AbstractRepeater.html) and [Fragment](http://wicket.apache.org/docs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/panel/Fragment.html). If you're willing to tell more about what you want to do and maybe provide some code too, I'll be happy to help as much as I can.

Answer (score 0):

you can call setVisible(false); on the component you want to hide.